# How would I access a system view in SQL Azure master database without logging into master?

Tags: permissions, access-control, azure-sql-database, master-system-database

My service needs to periodically read `sys.resource_stats` which is only in "master" database of SQL Azure server. The service currently only accesses a "regular" database in the same server. Accessing "master" requires adding a "user" in "master" which will be able to login there.

Adding a new "user" to "master" feels unsafe - it's not trivial to validate which privileges a "user" has, so it'd be better to not have any users except "admin" role users in "master".

SQL Azure doesn't allow referencing views/tables in other databases, so creating a view in the "regular" database which references a view in "master" is not an option.

Is there a way to reasonably solve this problem?